# How can you render complex dependency graph (dot) in a human readable way?

Tags: graphviz, dot, graph-visualization

I'm looking for a way to render dependency graphs (puppet resource graphs to be exact) in a human readable way. And by 'readable' I mean easily readable without the need of having to setup a cinema screen just to be able to completely display the relevant part.

Here is such a [graph](https://gist.github.com/michaelkrupp/d07640e1783c856702e8/raw/ad86f90992ecc6ab7920ffb9ce7a25949d8d6636/gistfile1.dot) I'm talking about.

If you render it via graphviz' `dot -Tpng`, it generates a about 16k x 3k pixel image which I absolutely cannot entirely display in any way that I could still read anything that's written there.

I'd like it to be more compact (less white space) and maybe different colors to help keeping track of the relationships more easily. Any hints on how to do that?

PS: The example graph actually is a quite simple one.

Comment: I've tried some different approaches to this graph. Setting `rankdir=LR` helps a bit (it makes the image squarer, for instance, and a little more compact because some of the node labels are quite long) but doesn't improve things a great deal. I think the issue is that the graph really isn't all that simple - there are quite a lot of nodes (in a number of clusters) and many edges (quite a few of which go between clusters). It might be necessary to filter the graph to extract clusters and view them one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use Gephi to filter the graph...

This [post](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/12/29/puppet-gephi-visualizing-infrastructure-as-code/) could help.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but very useful indeed.